# Local and global logarithms

Tags: complex-analysis

Plain and simple: Can each entire function $f$ without zeros be written in the form $e^g$ for some entire function $g$? What would be a counter-example?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{C}$ is simply connected: Yes, every zero-free entire function has a global logarithm.

Comment: @DanielFischer Why pass up the opportunity to point out that it has an explicit definition? Choose a point $a$, let $b$ be such that $e^b=a$, then $\displaystyle g(z):= b+\int_a^z \frac{f'(\zeta)}{f(\zeta)}\, d\zeta$ (where the path $a\to z$ is independent of choice by Cauchy's theorem, and the fact that we're in a simply connected domain) is holomorphic and $e^g=f$.

Answer (score 2):

Every zero-free holomorphic function $f$ on a simply connected domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ has a logarithm.

Since $\Omega$ is simply connected, the logarithmic derivative of $f$ has a primitive $h$, i.e.

$$h'(z) = \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}.$$

That means the function $f\cdot e^{-h}$ has derivative $\equiv 0$, so is constant. Choosing an appropriate constant, we obtain

$$f(z) = e^{h(z) + c}.$$

Since $\mathbb{C}$ is simply connected, that applies in particular to entire functions.