# there exists $h$ holomorphic function in $U$ such that $f=e^h$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am new to complex analysis, and I am unable to show the following result, if you have any tips please:
Let $f$ be a holomorphic function of a complex variable $z$ is  an open connected subset  $U$ such that $f(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in U$.

I want to show that : there exists $h$ holomorphic function in $U$ such that  $f=e^h$

Comment: You need $U$ to be simply connected, right?

Comment: @delta-divine Yes, to quantify your comment, one could say that: If $U$ is arbitrary, you can solve it for "some $f$", but if you want it to be solvable "for any $f$", you need $U$ to be simply connected.

Comment: Thanks, @DuchampGérardH.E.! Would you be willing to post an example where $U$ is open, connected but not simply connected, and the logarithm does not exist for some function $f$? I would be interested to see that.

Comment: OK, I can do it but it is rather trivial.

Comment: If it is trivial, then hints would be good @DuchampGérardH.E.

Comment: I did this formally below.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/512767/42969 – the question is about entire functions, but the answer is for arbitrary simply-connected domains.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1183777/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for your last link. I see that the discussion needs further elaboration (or validation). I'll return there ASAP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Theorem.** *(Existence of Logarithm)* If $f$ is a nowhere vanishing holomorphic function in a simply connected region $U$, then there exists a holomorphic function $F$ on $U$ such that $f(z) = e^{F(z)}$ for all $z\in U$.

*Proof.* Fix a point $z_0 \in U$. Define $$F(z):= \int_\gamma \frac{f'(w)}{f(w)}\, dw + c_0$$ where $\gamma$ is any curve in $U$ joining $z_0$ to $z$, and $c_0$ satisfies $e^{c_0} = f(z_0)$. By the homotopy version$\color{red}{^1}$ of Cauchy's theorem, $F$ is well-defined, i.e. it does not depend on the choice of $\gamma$. It is easy to check that
$$F'(z) = \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$$ for all $z\in U$. But then,
$$\frac{d}{dz}(fe^{-F})(z) = f(z) e^{-F(z)} (-F'(z)) + f'(z) e^{-F(z)} = 0$$
so that $f(z) = ce^{F(z)}$ for some constant $c\in \Bbb C$, for all $z\in U$. By the choice of $c_0$, we obtain $c = e^{c_0 - F(z_0)} = 1$, and hence
$$f(z) = e^{F(z)}$$ for all $z\in U$.

---

*Footnotes:*
$\color{red}{1.}$

> **Cauchy's Theorem**: If $f$ is holomorphic in a simply connected region $\Omega\subset\mathbb C$, then $\int_\gamma f(z)\, dz  = 0$ for any closed curve $\gamma$ in $\Omega$.

Comment: +1 good answer. One can quantify the problem, see my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

To complete delta-divine's answer, one can quantify the problem as follows. Let $\subset \mathbb{C}$ be an arbitrary open region and $\mathcal{H}(U)$ be the set of holomorphic functions $U\to \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{H}(U)^*$ that of functions vanishing nowhere (i.e. $f(U)\subset \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$). One has
$$
e^{\mathcal{H}(U)}\subset \mathcal{H}(U)^*
$$
delta-divine's answer shows that this inclusion is equality if $U$ is simply connected.
For an example where the inclusion is strict, one has
$U=\mathbb{C}^*=\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ as $f(z)=z$ is not an exponential.

Comment: Just to confirm, the reason for $f(z) = z$ not being an exponential is that $g(z) = \log z$ is holomorphic only on $\Bbb C\setminus [0, \infty)$, the slit complex plane, right?

Comment: Well, you can perfectly see the reason like that. You can also invoke the fact that, in $\mathbb{C}^*$, $dz/z$ is [closed but not exact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms) which can be proved by integrating if along any loop around zero.